# Marshmallow windowLightStatusBar = true not working in MI phone

Tags: android, statusbar

I want white color status bar and also want status bar icon with dark default color. but right now status bar color is white but status bar icon color not changed to dark default color. my theme code

value-v23/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

i set windowLightStatusBar as true its working in all device but not working in MI phone.

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

i attached screenshot of MI device and intex device. in MI device status bar icon showing in white color and in intex device showing in dark default color.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static boolean setMiuiStatusBarDarkMode(Activity activity, boolean darkmode) {
    Class<? extends Window> clazz = activity.getWindow().getClass();
    try {
        int darkModeFlag = 0;
        Class<?> layoutParams = Class.forName("android.view.MiuiWindowManager$LayoutParams");
        Field field = layoutParams.getField("EXTRA_FLAG_STATUS_BAR_DARK_MODE");
        darkModeFlag = field.getInt(layoutParams);
        Method extraFlagField = clazz.getMethod("setExtraFlags", int.class, int.class);
        extraFlagField.invoke(activity.getWindow(), darkmode ? darkModeFlag : 0, darkModeFlag);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

setMiuiStatusBarDarkMode(YourBaseActivity.this,true);
```

it works like a charm.

Comment: Seriously,i want to give more votes to this answer,:)

Comment: What if they change the class name MiuiWindowManager in the same OS version but different MIUI version? So if that happens this code will not work in the MIUI with different class name( MiuiWindowManager) right?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#windowLightStatusBar

> For this to take effect, the window must be drawing the system bar backgrounds with `windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` and the status bar must not have been requested to be translucent with `windowTranslucentStatus`